# Is there a list of all IOTA addresses with non-zero balances?

Tags: iri-legacy-api, iota-network

I would like to know if we could fetch the Tangle to find every addresses with non-zero balances, or if there is already an existing list of all non-zero addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a snapshot is done, all non-zero adresses are published with their balance.

Latest snapshot can be found here : https://gist.github.com/paulhandy/74fd70aa1156a7a152da1845358aed5f

This data is of course outdated (22.09.2017).

Otherwise, to get up-to-date data, you can setup a fullnode , make sure that it is properly sync, and extract this information from the DB.

Comment: If I understand correctly every snapshot remove history from the tangle so address in snapshot S-1 are not present in snapshot S-0 and addresses in snapshot S-0 are not in tangle ? So if I want a complete view I should check all snapshot ever made and the DB of a full node?

Comment: No. Every snapshot contains all addresses with non-zero value at snapshot time. If address owner din't make any transfer between snapshot-1 and snapshot-2 : you will see the exact same entry in both snapshots file (i.e. same address, same value)